# Angular 5 : How to write a Jasmine unit test for a data binding attribute

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular5, karma-jasmine

I need to write a unit test for a `data-binding` attribute of HTML element.

Here's the code:

```
<kendo-grid
            [kendoGridBinding]="gridData"
            [resizable]="true"
            style="height: 300px">
            <kendo-grid-column
                field="UnitPrice"
                title="Unit Price"
                [width]="180"
                filter="numeric"
                format="{0:c}">
            </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

I need to write a unit test for `resizable` attribute value.

What I tried so far:

```
  it('kendo-grid element should contain resizable attribute with "true" value', () => {
    const element = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('kendo-grid');
    expect(element.resizable).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

It is failing while running the Karma test runner.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to get the element like this instead? `const element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('kendo-grid'));` The `DebugElement` that you'll get will have a `properties` attribute that should have your `resizable` attribute in it.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Yes i tried this as well but did not get success.

Comment: What exactly spec file you are running? Is it a unit test of kendo-grid component or it's parent?

Comment: Okay, I got it. You have kendo-grid component as a child from UI library. But why do you need to test it for child? 
I suppose you have a variable instead of simple `true`. You need to test this variable instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These attributes converting to ng-reflect-{attributeName} in browser, so jasmine need to look for that attribute. The test below should work.

```
 it('kendo-grid element should contain resizable attribute with "true" value', () => {
    const element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('kendo-grid'));
    expect(element.nativeElement.getAttribute('ng-reflect-resizable')).toBe('true');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

As of today, there is a pitfall. I found a couple discussion, where people are complaining about this attributes. *Pawel Kozlowski* [said](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29222#issuecomment-471592080):

> I don't think anyone should be really using ng-reflect-... for
>   anything "serious" as those things are debug-mode only and won't be
>   available in a production build.

As I understand, `kendo-grid` is a 3rd party component. In this case, you should not test it for real, you just need integration tests to check it was implemented correctly. Therefore, you should not include `kendo` component into your TestBed config, and set `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing something like this. Can you try once.

```
const element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('kendo-grid'));
expect(element.nativeElement.resizable).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: I tried the same it is not working as `resizable` is not just an html attribute. It is a angular data-binding attribute enclosed in brackets `[]`

Comment: Well in that case, this doesn't even qualify to be tested in DOM. Sorry for not pointing this out coz I've no exposure in Kendo and understood this as resize property of HTML element.